# Java program to monitor other Java programs

Tags: java

I want to write a small admin tool that can start, stop, and monitor other Java non-GUI programs that either run continuously or are expected to complete?  This tool would run on the same server as the backend programs.  I would have a web front end for the administrator to use (probably with Jetty).  I would most likely want the backend programs to run as their own separate processes.

What if I wanted to communicate with those programs, such as query some detailed status?  The backend programs break up their computational work in ticks and between ticks, I could check for commands that come in.

Comment: Have you considered using [JMX](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Ftechnotes%2Fguides%2Fmanagement%2Fagent.html&ei=rBlnU7D-I9CgugTN0oHIBQ&usg=AFQjCNFrVsZPXnKNJ1XpaLLO73PqT76H2A&sig2=-qTzG-3yEHnRbpSQsj9jNA&bvm=bv.65788261,d.c2E) or the `jvisualvm` bundled with jdk1.8

Comment: @Parasu is this available in only jdk1.8 or later version also support this?

Comment: @Parasu also can't we give process name to the java program and monitor it using some unix or windows command whether application is still alive?

Comment: @Vishrant it is available in jdk1.6 as well, but i am not sure if it can connect to a remote vm.

Comment: @Vishrant if you just want to know if the process is alive or not, then you can get the PID and monitor it. If your sole purpose is to "restart" the dead process again, then you can configure it as re-spawnable process, so that it can respawn itself after it is dead.

Comment: @Parasu actually I was trying to get the PID for my application but when I run my executable jar file the process name was `java.exe` so I was not able to get process id if multiple jar files are running.

Comment: In a windows batch file `%%` will fetch you the PID of that prompt, whereas in unix shell scripts `$$` will fetch you the PID of that shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMX  has been a part of JRE since Java 1.5 it can be used to monitor local or remote java application.
Many java libraries/apps such as tomcat, jetty etc. have supported it by registering some JMX services.
If you want to a web front end for the administrator to use, you can try [jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) which is remote JMX with JSON over HTTP. It is fast, simple, polyglot and has unique features.